# "strike a resemblance", "have striking resemblance"

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I understand *striking resemblance* is often use with *bears*, is it correct to use *have striking resemblance* and *strike a resemblance*?

> The two of you *strike a resemblance*
>
> The two of you have striking resemblance

Comment: [It's more common to say "have **a** striking resemblance"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+striking+resemblance%2Chave+a+striking+resemblance&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20striking%20resemblance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20striking%20resemblance%3B%2Cc0), although you do see the version without an article.

Comment: "Striking resemblance" is way more often used when describing two humans. I'm really curious why you started with **bears**. :)

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use transitive ***to strike*** as in *X **struck** a resemblance to Y* - there's only the continuous participle used adjectivally to add emphasis *(a **striking** resemblance = a **strong / close / great** resemblance)* and the more explicitly metaphorical *X **struck a chord** with Y* (where 'Y' has to be a *person*, who is reminded of or in agreement with something associated with X).

Comment: @FeliniusRex hahaha... I phrased it poorly, I meant to say *They bear a striking resemblance* lol

Comment: @FlyingPenguin LOL ok. No worries!